# Didactic but for learning

Tags: single-word-requests

One [definition of `didactic`](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/didactic) is "designed to teach". Is there a similar adjective to describe something that is "designed to learn"?

For context: I am aiming to describe the qualities of an algorithm. I want to say the algorithm is fast, accurate, and able to learn (meaning its performance scales the more data it sees). I am hoping for a one-worder that summarizer "able to learn", but maybe the original phrase is sufficient.

Comment: There is a vast body of literature on computer/machine learning and AI. Have you done any research or considered any options?

Comment: I'd mirror Stuart's suggestion to look towards the literature. My mind initially jumps to "adaptive", as in "adaptive AI" which is AI that adapts, or "learns" from previous "experience". However, it is possible that "adaptive algorithm" has a technical, field-specific definition which doesn't fit your needs.